# How to do a light mode, dark mode theme in next.js for Full-calendar

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, fullcalendar

I have 1 variable indicates applications mode. How should I add to styling for Full-calendar with condition, I don’t want to use Bootstrap 5 because I already used Tailwind, is there any suggestion?  Thanks!

I cannot think of anyway to do this, as there are no condition in global.css and I can’t simply create a class with condition to overwrite previous style in Full-calendar ( I don’t know how to create css that impact other class than itself other than global.css, since every styling need className={Style.[classname]} and that doesn’t impact Full-calendar components)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can conditionally add class names to a react component.  How to do this for your use case depends on the full calendar library.  Can you share some of your code?